# CSS and Iframe. How to view the full page without scroll in the Iframe?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm trying to develop a Layout with CSS and using a Iframe. How can I show the full page in the iframe without scrolling? Is the iframe appropriate to show full web pages?

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="pt">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>layout basic method web</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        #container
        {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #fff;
        }

        iframe
        {
        border-style: none;
        width: 100%; 
        height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="top">
            <h1>Header</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <h2>Subheading</h2>
            <IFRAME name='iframe1' id="iframe1" src="http://www.yahoo.com"></IFRAME>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            Footer
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you test the code, you see that the CSS create a scroll inside the page. How can I get rid of this scroll and show all the page?

Best Regards,

---

UPDATE:

I'm almost there. I only need that the scroll up/down goes over the Header, just like goes over the footer. Is that possible? Please see the code. Just copy/paste it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title> stu nicholls | CSS PLaY | cross browser fixed header/footer layout basic method </title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #printhead {display:none;}

    html {
        height:100%; 
        max-height:100%; 
        padding:0; 
        margin:0; 
        border:0; 
        background:#fff; 
        font-size:80%; 
        font-family: "trebuchet ms", tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
        /* hide overflow:hidden from IE5/Mac */ 
        /* \*/ 
        /*overflow: hidden;*/ 
        /* */ 
    }

    body {height:100%; max-height:100%; overflow:hidden; padding:0; margin:0; border:0;}

    #content {display:block; height:100%; max-height:100%; overflow:hidden; padding-left:0px; position:relative; z-index:3; word-wrap:break-word;}

    /*#head {position:absolute; margin:0; top:0; right:18px; display:block; width:100%; height:50px; background:#fff; font-size:1em; z-index:5; color:#000; border-bottom:1px solid #000; }*/

    #head {position:absolute; margin:0; top:0; right:18px; display:block; width:100%; height:50px; background:#fff; color:#000; font-size:1em; border-bottom:1px solid #000;}

    #foot {position:absolute; margin:0; bottom:-1px; right:18px; display:block; width:100%; height:25px; background:#fff; color:#000; text-align:right; font-size:2em; z-index:4; border-top:1px solid #000;}

    .pad1 {display:block; width:18px; height:50px; float:left;}

    .pad2 {display:block; height:50px;}

    .pad3 {display:block; height:500px;}

    #content p {padding:5px;}

    .bold {font-size:1.2em; font-weight:bold;}

    .red {color:#c00; margin-left:5px; font-family:"trebuchet ms", "trebuchet", "verdana", sans-serif;}

    h2 {margin-left:5px;}

    h3 {margin-left:5px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="head">
    <div class="pad1"></div><h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<div id="content">
<div class="pad2"></div>
    <IFRAME name="teste" src="http://www.yahoo.com" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder=0></IFRAME>
<!--<div class="pad3"></div>-->
</div>
<div id="foot">Footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any clues on how to achieve this?

Best Regards,

Comment: use of iframe necessary? You should look into ajax. I maybe wrong, depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't know if iframe is what I should use. I need to develop a layout that show's full websites like yahoo, google, ect.. but the user is keept in my domain(www.mydomain.com) to see a Header and a Footer. Should I use iframes or should I use other technique?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to set the height of the iframe to match the height of the page you are looking at.

If the page is within the same domain you could use javascript to dynamically resize the frame to match the body size of the page you are viewing. There's a few jQuery plugins out there that will do that.

If it's an external domain you can't do this so you'll have to just set the height property of the iframe to match.

Comment: The layout will work only with external domain's. So the iframe could be a wrong choice. What should I use to work with external domains?

Comment: @Andre: An iframe does look like what you are looking for since an ajax request will load the page initialy but any further navigation will take you away from your own page. As  far as I'm aware you will be stuck with scrollbars if you want to ensure full page visibility.

Comment: I have made an update to the post. I'm almost there. I can go over the footer with the scroll down but not over the header. It should be possible to go over the header too?

Comment: It's certainly possible to go over the header. the problem is that once you have achieved this you will have a cut-off from the top of the page within the iframe.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get rid of the scrollbar on the main window, add an `overflow` style:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tested. But it seems that iframe is not the tool for what I achieve to do. I will work only with external domains

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with javascript:

```
   function resizeFrame(){
    var iframe = parent.document.getElementById('id of your iframe');  
    $(iframe).height($('#your top html tag inside your iframe').height());
    $(iframe).width($('#your top html tag inside your iframe').width());
   }
```

Then call this function on load & after any hide/unhide actions that will change the form length:
       resizeFrame();

If you have margins/padding on the top level html tag inside the iframe, you might need to add px to the height() / width() like this:

```
    $(iframe).height($('#your top html tag inside your iframe').height()+40);
    $(iframe).width($('#your top html tag inside your iframe').width()+20);
```

Comment: Thank you Mate! :D

Answer (score 0):

An iframe cannot adjust size relative to the page it is showing. You would need to adjust it's size with javascript, which implies that you know the size of the page beforehand. If you are just after showing the content of another page inside yours, indeed have a look at ajax.

A very simple example can be found here: 
http://aleembawany.com/2005/09/01/ajax-instant-tutorial

be aware that loading pages with ajax in a cross-domain context might not work due to security settings of the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will work only with external domains(contents of other pages inside my page). How is the best way to deal with this subject?

Comment: Ajax cannot load pages cross-domain due to potential security implications. You'd need a "proxy" on your own domain to gather the data for you. Via ajax you make a call to your proxy page on your own domain. The proxy could be a php page that does an fgets on a remote page and returns it's content to your ajax call. Here is an example with php and jQuery's Ajax: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html

Comment: Hi, that is a good idea, but will work for example with pages in flash? I have updated the post. I'm almost there. I only need to go with the scroll over the header section, the scroll goes over the footer but not over the header. It should be possible to achieve this?